# If a commission of 20% is given on retail price, the profit is 60%. Find the profit if the commission is increased by 5% of the retail price

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If a commission of 20% is given on retail price, the profit is 60%. Find the profit percentage when the commission is increased by 5% of the retail price.

What will be the effect of commission on selling price? I did not understand this at all.

Answer (score 2):

The commission does not have any effect on the selling price, but it affects the profit. You can calculate profit as $\frac{(\text{Selling price}) - (\text{Original cost}) - (\text{Commission})}{\text{Original cost}}\times 100\%$.

Does that help? It might make it all more concrete to just assume the original cost was $100$.

---

More detail, assuming original cost is $100$:

$$\frac{S.P. - 100 - (.20)(S.P.)}{100}=.60$$

Therefore:

$$(.80)(S.P.) - 100 = 60$$

does that give you a push in the right direction?

Comment: How commission effects the profit? @GTonyJacobs

Comment: According to the formula I just gave you. If you have to pay the sales rep a higher commission, then you make less profit.

Comment: I did not get the right answer @GTonyJacobs

Comment: Well, tell me more. What did you get for the selling price? The more you can tell me about the work you did, the more I can help you.

Comment: I took the original cost as Rs 100, then there is 60% profit hence selling price became 160 but there is commission of 20%, hence SP became 140...@GTonyJacobs

Comment: Ok, since the profit means profit *after* commission, then the selling price must have been more than 160. Also, when you calculate commission, it's a percent of the selling price, not a percent of the original price.

Comment: But you said that commission affects the profit right? So firstly I calculated the amount after profit...160. Now 20% of 160=32. Now my new Selling price will be 128. Is it right now? @GTonyJacobs

Comment: The commission affects the profit, so when we say the profit is 60%, we mean *after* commission. Profit means profit at the end of the day, after all expenses are paid. The selling price has to be higher if the profit is still going to be 60% after paying commission.